# Как узнать какая кнопка нажата, если они создаются циклом?

Tags: java, android

В цикле создается n-ное количество кнопок, и создается для них всех 1 общий listener, как в нем узнать какая из кнопок нажата?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно использовать `setTag();`

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
     Button btn = new Button(this);
     btn.setTag(i);
     btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnclickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             int i = v.getTag();
             switch(i) {
                 case 1: btn.setText(i); break;
                 case 2: btn.setText(i); break;
                 case 3: btn.setText(i); break;
                 case 4: btn.setText(i);break;
                 default: btn.setText("Others");
             }
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Метод класса-листенера по обработке события принимает аргумент - View, спровоцировавшее событие => внутри метода по обработке нажатия определяйте уникальное значение какого-либо свойства вью. ID, например:

```
new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch(v.getId())
                {
                    case ID_1: break;
                    case ID_2: break;
                    default: break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: В этом то и проблема, они создаются циклом и у них нету уникальных свойств

Comment: Так сложно его назначить? Например, тем же View.setId()

Comment: А как создать id на лету?(что передавать в View.setId())

Comment: Любой целочисленный идентификатор. Обычно их следует хранить в константах.